# problem iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

i've xcode 4.0 with sdk 4, and i've big problems with iphone simulator.
Many times freeze on splashscreen, other after some times, for example a timer will not work at all, to resume the function of app i need to press 2-3 times home button adn reenter....why this? is a common bug?

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way to find out where the bugs are in your code.

Answer (score 0):

... well, a test to see if it's a broken install of the simuator: does any of the sample projects apple has in the documentation build and run normally? Or do you have a very high CPU load or low memory during the simulator runs?

If it's just your code, you should post the important parts here as the commentator above suggests.

To answer your question: no, your problems are not common (at least, I never had this).